# Memcache in windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel

Is there any way to Memcache not found as cache driver for Laravel in windows? The  only solution that I have found so far way to change the CACHE_DRIVER in ENV to 'array' from 'memcached'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the memcache extension enabled in you php.ini

Here you can find the right extenson dll for windows and php7.
https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll

You are still in need for a running memcache server to make this work.
You can find an installation guide for windows here
https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows